# for in and for of loops

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

2 quick questions

1. How do I access the index position in an array using for...of?
2. How do I access the value in an array using for...in?

Pseudo code

```
var arr = [3, 5, 7];
var pos, value;

for (pos in arr) {
   console.log(pos); // logs "0", "1", "2"
}

for (value of arr) {
   console.log(value); // logs "3", "5", "7"
}
```

Comment: you may want to change the variable `i`

Comment: use this `arr.map(function(value, index, array){...})` or `arr.forEach(function(value, index, arr){...})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the value in for in simply by using the index on the original array:

```
var arr = [3, 5, 7];
var pos, value;

for (pos in arr) {
   console.log(arr[pos]); // logs 3, 5, 7
}
```

Note that using for...in to iterate arrays is a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea).

Getting the index in `for…of` requires an external counter:

```
var arr = [3, 5, 7];
var pos = 0, value;

for (value of arr) {
   console.log(pos++); // logs 0, 1, 2
}
```

A better solution for both cases would be `Array.prototype.forEach`:

```
arr.forEach((value, index) => {
    console.log('index: ', index);
    console.log('value: ', value);
});
```

Comment: Note: `indexOf` will return the index of the first occurance of the value, not the index where that value actually came from, so it only works if all the values are unique.

Comment: Thanks @Guffa - added a fix for that.

Comment: Why do you need to search for it at all, instead of just `pos++`?

Answer (score 7):

There is a way:

```
for (let [key, value] of arr.entries()) {
    // ...
}
```

It uses the [`Array.prototype.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) which returns an iterator over tuples of `(key; value)` and [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) that turns it into 2 separated variables.

And to address your answer in particular: when you iterate over arrays you should use either `for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)` or `for-of`, [but not `for-in`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572).

Comment: This is very unusual for my eyes. Didn't know you can do that. Seems like the future of Javascript, ES6.

Comment: @Vennsoh: Well, yeah, `for…of` is ES6…

Answer (score 0):

Using `for...in`

```
for (pos in arr) {
   console.log(arr[pos]);// logs "3", "5", "7"
}
```

There is no way using `for...of`. This will give you an idea.

```
var arr = ["3", 3, {}, true];

for (value of arr) {
    console.log(typeof value);
}
```